Matrix similarity conditions
I need to find out if three matrices are similar to each other (Yes/No + Reason). Is it sufficient to show that the determinants, rank, trance, and eigenvalues are the same?

Are you saying that $[[2,2][2,2]]$ and $[[3,3][3,3]]$ are similar or not?

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is not similar to $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ but they have the same determinant, rank, trace and eigenvalues
